# Windows 10 machine stuck in Greyscale mode

Tags: windows-10, grayscale

My lovely cat walked across my keyboard and now my Windows user profile is completely stuck in grey-scale mode. I have done all the typical things like disabling Color Filters, and checking Color Management. I have also checked my NVIDIA Control Panel, and all color profiles etc. are simply default.

I have also confirmed that this is not a monitor issue, as this affects all 3 of my monitors, and switching users fixes the issue.

Am I missing something here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Although improbable as you have disable Color filters, try pressing Win+Ctrl+C to check if the grayscale toggle is enabled.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

After a brainwave, it was discovered that grayscale mode had been accidentally activated in f.lux by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: Apparently you're not the only one! (TBH started to suspect f.lux after Windows dabbling didn't prove useful).